# How do I commit at the same time to multiple VS solutions that have files in common?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, gitlab, git-commit

I have two Visual Studio C# solutions that share some .cs projects, and I wanna know if there's a way to, if I commit and push (to GitLab) on one solution, the other one also gets updated, so I don't need to commit on both separately.

I wanna have one repository for solution A and one for solution B, but they must have a project in common (a few projects actually). If I'm coding on these projects on solution A and commit them, are they/how do they get updated on solution B repository?

Comment: I believe you're not asking the question correctly because this doesn't make sense. You wouldn't commit on one and force a commit on all, you would do something like commit on one and pull on the rest.  However; keeping them current on each via commits isn't the proper way to use git so I'm confused.  Can you explain a little clearer what your intent is?

Comment: Are those two completely separate repositories? I mean, not one being a clone of the other?

Comment: If you want to share the same cs projects, it good to create a share library, ex: Project.Core. Build this project as nuget package and add this nuget package in both solutions.

Comment: If they share some projects, either the common projects should be nuget packages (this is unlikely, unless you're very organized), or they should all be in the same repo. But in the meantime, you can make a powershell script to do all of your pushing.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough: I haven't done it yet cause I didn't found out how to. I wanna have one repository for solution A and one for solution B, but they must have a project in common (a few projects actually). If I'm coding on these projects on solution A and commit them, are they/how do they get updated on solution B repository?